# Not able to debug with Flex Builder 3

Tags: apache-flex

I use Flex for a short time, use a bit pushed to my client for a solution-oriented monitoring.

Background:

Platform:

- Windows XP
- Eclipse 3.4 Ganymede
- Flex Builder 3.0.2 Licenced
- JDK 1.6_20
- Firefox 3.6
- Flash Player 9 (Debug version)
- Server: OSGI (Eclipse equinox) an
  instance of jetty service allows HTTP
  requests

**Requirements**: 
Make debugger in ActionScript by putting "BreakPoint" to assess the contents of variables.

**Problem**: 
The code does not stop at breakpoint, worse, if a breakpoint is enabled, the module flex does not start.

**Actions**: 
Reinstall all the dev environment (Eclipse, Flex Builder, Flash Player): KO 
Removing repo maven modules and complete rebuilds: KO 
Restarting Windows: °) KO

Logs: 
this is what the log contains just after launching the platform (modules) in debug mode.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
Has com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.breakpoints.FlexLineBreakpoint.findSourceFiles (FlexLineBreakpoint.java: 388) 
Has com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.breakpoints.FlexLineBreakpoint.instantiate (FlexLineBreakpoint.java: 442) 
Has com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget.breakpointAdded (FlexDebugTarget.java: 981) 
Has com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget $ FdbThread.installDeferredBreakpoints (FlexDebugTarget.java: 631) 
Has com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget $ FdbThread.advanceStateMachine (FlexDebugTarget.java: 662) 
Has com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget FdbThread.access $ $ 6 (FlexDebugTarget.java: 636) 
Has com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget $ 1.run (FlexDebugTarget.java: 738) 
Has org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run (SafeRunner.java: 37) 
Has org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run (Platform.java: 880) 
Has com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget $ FdbThread.eventLoop (FlexDebugTarget.java: 718) 
Has com.adobe.flexbuilder.debug.model.FlexDebugTarget $ FdbThread.run (FlexDebugTarget.java: 779) 
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java: 619)
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause described in the comment by the author of this question (user361222)  is correct. 
I have 2 additional tips:

1. after you change the container swf to debug version, you should clear IE caches. I meet problem after I change container swf to debug version, I still cannot debug, but after I clear browser cache, it works.
2. You don't have to use "nemo440" to see it the swf is debug version. You can right click the flash GUI of your container swf(should before the child swf loading), if the debug menu in the context menu is enabled, the swf is debug version.

If before the child swf load the "debug" menu is disable, but after the child swf load the debug menu is enable, then you must have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try updating your debug player to see if that has an affect.

http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Where does that log come from?  Is it an eclipse log?  Or something you see on the server?  Is Eclipse crashing?

When you use the 'term' Module are you referring to Flex Modules ( http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/modules/Module.html ) or are you using the term more generically?

If using Modules; have you tried to test the module separate from the rest of the application?  Create an application that is the Module instead of using the ModuleLoader.  Does that have an affect?

Which version of the Flex SDK are you using?  Can you upgrade to 3.5 or 4.0 ?

Comment: Thanks
we finally found the "clue", it resides within yes or no the swf is a debug one or a release one.
a debug swf has some debug information included, a tool like nemo440 (http://goo.gl/JOR0) can help find them.
I posted a question on the Adobe flex forum, here's the link and the answer. (http://goo.gl/Do5u)

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to do following :

1. Export preferences and exit Eclipse
2. Delete `.metadata` folder
3. Launch Eclipse and recreate the workspace
4. Import preferences.

It works all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the 32bits version of Firefox...

Got the same issue and i resolved it by installing win32 version of Firefox...